# Building WM C++ project outside an IDE

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

I'm wondering if there is some comprehensive tutorial or someone of you can help me solve this problem.
I need to build Windows mobile project written in C++ but I need to do so outside of any IDE. So I would be very grateful if someone could direct me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can call devenv directly with the [/build switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) and pass it the project name and it will build without opening the IDE.  Or do you want to be able to build without an IDE even installed?  In that case you could write an [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) script that would do it.